# Optimization gives incorrect image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, optimization, vectorization

im working with images double(800x450x3) and I want to change the value of a pixel if it holds certain conditions. However the code that i first had works and gives me a good image. When i tried to optimize it the image will get really strange colors (red/purple/blue etc) when I don't have them at all in the previous case.

First i had the code:

```
diff = abs(double(rgbimage) - double(backgroundImage));
fusion = zeros(size(currentFrame));
 for i=1:size(backgroundImage,1)
    for j = 1:size(backgroundImage,2)

       if diff(i,j) > 20

        fusion(i,j, :) = double(rgbimage(i,j, :));

       else
         fusion(i,j, :) = 0;  

       end
    end 
 end
```

and i optimized it to:

```
    diff = abs(double(rgbimage) - double(backgroundImage));
    fusion = zeros(size(currentFrame));    
    indexes = diff > 20;
    fusion(indexes) = double(rgbimage(indexes));
```

...and after I just plot

```
    subplot(2,1,1), subimage(uint8(fusion));
    title('Fusion');
```

What's the difference and why do i get this error?
Thanks!

Comment: Its a bad idea to named your variable diff, as then the function diff will be in conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your two methods are different is because you, in the for-loop version, use only the first "layer" of the difference image (i would guess the red component?). Your line `if diff(i,j) > 20` is interpreted as `if diff(i,j,1) > 20`. If the third coordinate is not defined in a look-up it defaults to `1`.

The optimized code compares all elements of the 3-dimensional data structure - element-by-element. This is why you get "weird" colors. The difference check is thus made locally in every pixel and does not take color components into consideration.

Try doing this with your optimized version:

```
diff = abs(double(rgbimage) - double(backgroundImage));
fusion = zeros(size(currentFrame));
indexes = cat( ...
   3, ...
   diff(:,:,1) > 20, ...
   diff(:,:,1) > 20, ...
   diff(:,:,1) > 20 ...
);
fusion(indexes) = double(rgbimage(indexes));
```

This should now give the same result as the for-loop version.

Comment: `repmat(diff(:,:,1)>20,[1 1 3])` would be cleaner.

Comment: Sure :) And your other fine point was removed. So I have removed my long comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest instead of subtracting images manually use, imsubtract
   internal function . (Subtract one image from another or subtract
   constant from image). Z = imsubtract(X,Y) subtracts each element in
   array Y from the corresponding element in array X and returns the
   difference in the corresponding element of the output array Z. X and
   Y are real, nonsparse numeric arrays of the same size and class, or
   Y is a double scalar. The array returned, Z, has the same size and
   class as X unless X is logical, in which case Z is double.
2. And do not convert images manually to double type and use im2double
       internal function:  I2 = im2double(I) converts the intensity image I
       to double precision, rescaling the data if necessary.
3. Also you may use find function, [row,col,v] = find(X, ...) returns a
   column or row vector v of the nonzero entries in X, as well as row
   and column indices. If X is a logical expression, then v is a
   logical array. Output v contains the non-zero elements of the
   logical array obtained by evaluating the expression X.

   [r,c,v]= find(diff>20);